# Как вставить значение переменной в поле свойства ЧИСЛО, выводимой на редактирование в ФОрме добавления/редактирования элементов?

Tags: битрикс

Имеется инфоблок со свойством типа Число, при добавлении элементов в публичной части через форму добавления/редактирования элементов, на редактирование  выводится это свойство. Так же в форму передается через глобальную переменную определенное значение, которое является так же числом. Как подставить значение, которое дает нам переменная в поле свойства ЧИСЛО? Без участия пользователя, автоматически.

При этом, это не обязательно выводить это свойство в форму чисто визуально,  то есть, выводить то придется, чтобы заполнить и сохранить свойство, но,  поскольку весь процесс скрыт от юзера, то и смотреть ему там не на что,  тем более, что данные ему там будут не понятны и если не видно будет, то и отредактировать он его не сможет, это плюс. В крайнем случае, вывести и запретить редактирование.

Comment: Если это универсальный список, то там есть при настройке галочка показывать или нет в форме редактирования. Форму добавления элемента тоже можно настроить скрыв это поле.

Comment: хорош бы настроить, это форма добавления add.element form.
Подсказку получил, что можно все это делать в обработчике через OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd...